# Modifying observableArray does not instantly update select UI

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have a multi-select dropdown. If the user selects the option `all`, I want all the other options to be deselected and only select `all`. I have this almost working, but my issue is that the `select` does not show the updated value until minimise the dropdown. The state of the `observableArray` appears to be correct.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: games, selectedOptions: selectedGame, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'" multiple="true"></select>
```

And the javascript:

```
this.games= [
{ 
    name: 'All',
    id: 'all'
}, 
{ 
    name: 'Game1',
    id: 'game1'
},
{ 
    name: 'Game2',
    id: 'game2'
},  
] 

this.selectedGame = ko.observableArray(['all']);
this.selectedGameBeforeChange = ko.observableArray([]);

this.selectedGame.subscribe((oldValue) => 
{
    this.selectedGameBeforeChange(oldValue);
}, null, 'beforeChange');

this.selectedGame.subscribe((newValue) => 
{
    const newValueAdded = newValue.filter(x => !this.selectedGameBeforeChange().includes(x));
    if (newValueAdded.length > 0 && newValueAdded[0] === 'all'){
        this.selectedGame.removeAll();
        this.selectedGame.push('allCombined');    
    }

    this.updateTable();
});
```

The code above works, but the change is only reflected in the UI once I have 'minimised' the select and reopen it. Is there a way to force the UI to update as soon my `observableArray` is updated?

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your problem? if so, please mark it as accepted. if not, let me know so I could further help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 2 bugs:

1. Instead of `push('allCombined')`, it should be `push('all')`.
2. It works when `all` is selected last, but not when it's selected as the first option. To fix that, we need to modify the condition a bit.

Here's the final code (with few more minor modifications, e.g using `self` instead of `this`):

```js
var vm = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.games = [
    { name: 'All', id: 'all' }, 
    { name: 'Game1', id: 'game1' },
    { name: 'Game2', id: 'game2' }  
  ]; 
  self.selectedGames = ko.observableArray(['all']);
  self.selectedGamesBeforeChange = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.selectedGames.subscribe((oldValue) => 
  {
      self.selectedGamesBeforeChange(oldValue);
  }, null, 'beforeChange');

  self.selectedGames.subscribe((newValue) => 
  {
      if (newValue.length > 1 && 
          newValue.includes('all')){
          self.selectedGames.removeAll();
          self.selectedGamesBeforeChange.removeAll();
          self.selectedGames.push('all'); 
      }
  });
};
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: games, selectedOptions: selectedGames, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'" multiple="true"></select>
```